Does it matter whether I got a PhD in (applied) math or computer science?
I'm currently a third year PhD student in computer science. I got master degrees in both computer science and mathematics. My research is quite different from the other members of my group and is actually more about mathematics (stochastic PDEs, Markov processes, ...) with applications in computer science. For that reason, I was asked whether I want to pursue a doctoral in computer science or mathematics (but I guess it would be "applied mathematics").
I don't want to work in academia after my PhD, but in a R&D deparment in the industry. Does it actually matter wheter I choose computer science or (applied) mathematics for my PhD? I guess what's actually more important is the actual research I'm doing. However, the first impression of me would be the kind of PhD I got, I guess. So, I don't know what would be benefical for me.

There'd likely be less of a kneejerk reaction if you applied with a computer science degree. Frankly it depends where you apply. Ask folks in your network though.
